# Got the following error when rendering my React-App "[eslint] Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from."

Tags: reactjs

I got the following error everytime I render my react app.

[eslint] Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from.

this is the package.json file of my react web application

```
{
  "name": "monstors-rolodex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
    
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help to reslove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
yarn add eslint-config-react-app -D
```